# Behaviour of pandas groupby on Timedelta

Tags: python, pandas, timedelta

Let's create the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({"id":[1,2],
                     "time": [pd.Timedelta(seconds=3), pd.Timedelta(minutes=1.5)]})
```

I wonder why the following two commands return different results:

- `data.groupby("id").max().time`

versus

- `data.groupby("id").time.max()`

They both return a dataframe that, as expected, returns the maximal Timedelta for each code, But the first of them returns it in the usual format,

`1   00:00:03
2   00:01:30`

while the second returns the Timedelta as an integer representing the time in nanoseconds:

`1     3000000000
2    90000000000`

Why does this conversion occur? 
`int(pd.TimeDelta(minutes=1.5))` does not even exist.

Thanks.

Comment: I can't reproduce this using Pandas 0.19.2

Comment: @MaxU I use Pandas 0.18.1